# Placeholder/ cell label in specific column datatable shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to get the **placeholder or cell name** for a specific column in editable datatable in shiny R. This would ensure user aware that a specific column can be edit.

I provide some example of code. Instead of column count show value 0, I want a placeholder/cell label would appear like **"double click here to input value"**.
I don't want to store iris$count <- "double click to input"

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
)

server <- shinyServer (
  function (input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$table3_cell_edit,{
      info = input$table3_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col
      v = info$value
      vals$df_input <<- editData(vals$df_input, info)
      
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable (iris, 
                                         editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list( columns = c(1,2,3,4,5)) ))
  
    }
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is what current code produce

[image]

What i want something like this
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/808). Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't wok for me. Is it because I store the empty cell with 0 value?

Comment: okay it does work for me thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

CSS <- "
table td.withPlaceholder:empty:before {
  content: 'Double click here to input value';
  color: gray;
}
"

iris$count <- ""
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(CSS))
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
)

server <- shinyServer (
  function (input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$table3_cell_edit,{
      info = input$table3_cell_edit
      str(info)
      i = info$row
      j = info$col
      v = info$value
      vals$df_input <<- editData(vals$df_input, info)
      
    })
    
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable (iris, 
                                         editable = list(target = 'cell', disable = list( columns = c(1,2,3,4,5)) ),
                                         options = list( columnDefs = list(list(targets = 6, className = "withPlaceholder")))
                                         )
    
  }
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```